# looking through string arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the below piece of code doing?
e.g. 'Touch Screens' is passed in as str.
It makes an array out of the string 'Touch Screens'. 
what does the -1 mean? if the array has -1? return \ + ??

```
private static readonly char[] CharsToEncode = new[] { '"', '\r', '\n', ',', '\t' };

        private string CheckCharacters(String str)
        {
            if (str.IndexOfAny(CharsToEncode) != -1)
            {
                return "\"" + str.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
            }
            else
            {
                return str;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If `str` includes any of `CharsToEncode` then replace `"` with `""` and enclose whole string within `"` so for example `ABC",DEF` will become `"ABC"",DEF"`

Answer (score 2):

The "-1" value means there was no any `CharsToEncode` found so you just return your string back. If it has any `CharsToEncode` you're returning the string of value \" + (text where every \" is replaced with \"\") + \" which represents "text""" to us humans in case where string input was (text").

You should take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50(v=vs.110).aspx

Return Value

Type: System.Int32

The zero-based index position of the first occurrence in this instance where any character in anyOf was found; -1 if no character in anyOf was found.